# Check if variant has value at compile time

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates, std-variant

Can't use `variant.index()` in constexpr statements so need to iterate variant and return `true` if it can cast to some type or `false` if it's emtpy or contains zero value. Try this code, but seems index sequence is not variadic type and ... operator not available in this case.

```
template <typename T>
bool has_value(T value) noexcept {
    if constexpr (std::is_convertible_v <T, bool>) {
        return value;
    }
    else if constexpr (is_variant_v<T>) {
        constexpr size_t N = std::variant_size_v<decltype(value)>;
        using variant_sequence = typename std::make_index_sequence<0, N-1>::type;
        bool __has_value = (( std::get<variant_sequence>(value), true) || variant_sequence... ) ;
        return __has_value;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Empty, you mean `std::monostate` or T == `std::variant<>` (which is ill formed)? [`std::visit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit) is `constexpr` BTW.

Comment: I have some variadic variant, which is user setting, for example variant<int, long, double>. I have this Targs... separatly but don't want to use them everytime I work with variant type. So I want to parse this variant without Ts... giving this sequence from variant type itself immediately. Seems with combination of variant_length and index sequence it is possible.

Comment: I also have some variable which is same variant type, and I initialise this variable zero value in declaration, maybe I can simply check initial value with literal 0 in std::get method but I am not sure that it is correct way to check complex variant value.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want:

```
template <typename T>
bool has_value(T value) noexcept {
    if constexpr (std::is_convertible_v <T, bool>) {
        return value;
    } else if constexpr (is_variant_v<T>) {
        return std::visit([](const auto& elem){ return has_value(elem); }, value);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Exactly! Thank you!